# Mask or hide on-premise Power BI Report Server name

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

We have on-premise Power BI Report Server we use to share reports with internal users. I would like to hide/mask the report server name when sharing the link. We do not want the user to see the Server Name.

How can I achieve this in a link similar to one shown below?

http://ServerName/Reports/powerbi/MyFolder/MyReport

Comment: somehow I don't think it is possible unless it is embedded in another application that calls RS to deliver

Comment: Thanks, Harry! We will look into that option.

Answer (score 0):

1. List item go to report server configuration manager  then go to web portal url tab and click advanced then add ip or name
2. if you have network  you can use localhost or ip in first of url
3. you can write a web application for hiding the web portal and your users seen your UI
4. if you have web or desktop application you can use query string or url directing